# Issues while installing Anaconda3

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, anaconda

After following the installation instructions, I am stuck here.

The step during Anaconda installation where I am getting error:

```
Please answer ‘yes‘ or ‘no‘:‘
>>> yes

Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/hone/sonal/anaconda3

- Press ENTER to confirm the location
- Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
- Or specify a different location below

[/hone/sonal/anaconda3] >>>
```

> ERROR: File or directory already exists: ‘/hone/sonal/anac&1da3‘
>       If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option.
>       sonal@sonal-HP-Notebook:/tmp$

Can anybody help me solving this?

Comment: It appears youre reinstalling it. Use the `-u` as suggested by the error message ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code / error messages` into your question, including what line gives you that error. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please see my EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

two way as follows

1. First: rm -rf /home/sonal/anaconda3 Second: reinstall acaconda3

or

2. use `-u` with your install command

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an existing installation directory of anaconda3. You need to remove the old installation directory and reinstall or you can update as well.

To update:
You can just run the command with '-u' option as mentioned in the screenshot itself.

To Reinstall:
Run the following commands:

1. Remove anaconda3 directory
   rm -rf ~/anaconda3
2. Remove anaconda path in the PATH variable. Edit ~/.bashrc file.
3. Remove other hidden files.
   rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
4. Re-run the installation script.